# rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpVelocity); doesn't make character jump (Unity2D)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am pretty new to unity and have followed a tutorial on how to add the ability to move and jump to the player. The movement works fine but no matter what I do the jumping does nothing.
Any help would be appreciated! The script is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float move = 0f;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float jumpVelocity;

    Vector2 movement;
   
    void Start()
    {
        jumpVelocity = 10f;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Someone pressed space");
           
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpVelocity);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try specifying the ForceMode? For example, `rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpVelocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);`

Comment: Are you using kinematic rigid body? AddForce only works for non-kinematic bodies whereas MovePosition works for only kinematic ones.

Comment: have you added a rigidbody? and is the rigidbody kinimatic. also try to increase the jump force. also do at the end at the addforce * Time.deltaTime so it goes smoothly